# Android connect to database via PHP file E/Buffer Error﹕ Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am trying to develop a museum search app and try to list my php JSON results in a listView but i can not access my JSON results from Android, i will submit my code and the error messages i get:

DisplaySearchResultsActivity.java

```
package com.cloudlionheart.museumsearchapplication;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplaySearchResultsActivity extends ListActivity {
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> museumItemsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_search_results = "http://192.168.56.1/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEMS = "museum_items";
    private static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ID = "museum_item_id";
    private static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_NAME = "museum_item_name";
    private static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ARTIST = "museum_item_artist";
    private static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_HISTORICAL_PERIOD = "museum_item_historic_period";
    private static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_LOCATION = "museum_item_location";
    private static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_IMAGE = "museum_list_image";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray museumItems = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_search_resaults);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        museumItemsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DisplaySearchResultsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Museum Items. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_search_results, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Museum Items: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    museumItems = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEMS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < museumItems.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = museumItems.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable

                        String item_id = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ID);
                        String item_name = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_NAME);
                        String item_artist = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ARTIST);
                        String item_historic_period = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_HISTORICAL_PERIOD);
                        String item_location = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_LOCATION);
                        String list_image = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_IMAGE);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ID, item_id);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_NAME, item_name);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ARTIST, item_artist);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_HISTORICAL_PERIOD, item_historic_period);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_LOCATION, item_location);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_IMAGE, list_image);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        museumItemsList.add(map);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * *
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            DisplaySearchResultsActivity.this, museumItemsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ID,
                            TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_NAME, TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ARTIST,
                            TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_HISTORICAL_PERIOD, TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_LOCATION,
                            TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_IMAGE},
                            new int[]{R.id.museum_item_id, R.id.museum_item_name,
                                    R.id.museum_item_artist, R.id.museum_item_historic_period,
                                    R.id.museum_item_location, R.id.museum_list_image});
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

JSONParser.java

```
package com.cloudlionheart.museumsearchapplication;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplaySearchResultsActivity extends ListActivity {
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> museumItemsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_search_results = "http://192.168.56.1/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEMS = "museum_items";
    private static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ID = "museum_item_id";
    private static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_NAME = "museum_item_name";
    private static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ARTIST = "museum_item_artist";
    private static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_HISTORICAL_PERIOD = "museum_item_historic_period";
    private static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_LOCATION = "museum_item_location";
    private static final String TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_IMAGE = "museum_list_image";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray museumItems = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_search_resaults);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        museumItemsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DisplaySearchResultsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Museum Items. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_search_results, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Museum Items: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    museumItems = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEMS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < museumItems.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = museumItems.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable

                        String item_id = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ID);
                        String item_name = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_NAME);
                        String item_artist = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ARTIST);
                        String item_historic_period = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_HISTORICAL_PERIOD);
                        String item_location = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_LOCATION);
                        String list_image = c.getString(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_IMAGE);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ID, item_id);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_NAME, item_name);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ARTIST, item_artist);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_HISTORICAL_PERIOD, item_historic_period);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_LOCATION, item_location);
                        map.put(TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_IMAGE, list_image);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        museumItemsList.add(map);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * *
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            DisplaySearchResultsActivity.this, museumItemsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ID,
                            TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_NAME, TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_ARTIST,
                            TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_HISTORICAL_PERIOD, TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_LOCATION,
                            TAG_MUSEUM_ITEM_IMAGE},
                            new int[]{R.id.museum_item_id, R.id.museum_item_name,
                                    R.id.museum_item_artist, R.id.museum_item_historic_period,
                                    R.id.museum_item_location, R.id.museum_list_image});
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

and i get the following errors.

```
05-07 10:27:07.177    1942-1962/com.cloudlionheart.museumsearchapplication E/Buffer Error﹕ Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
05-07 10:27:07.177    1942-1962/com.cloudlionheart.museumsearchapplication E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
05-07 10:27:07.181    1942-1962/com.cloudlionheart.museumsearchapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.cloudlionheart.museumsearchapplication.DisplaySearchResultsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(DisplaySearchResultsActivity.java:94)
            at com.cloudlionheart.museumsearchapplication.DisplaySearchResultsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(DisplaySearchResultsActivity.java:69)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

After hours of search and tries i still can't find the way to make it work

Comment: could you please upload you log here else please print your json result here

Comment: post your json response. and make you sure you are receiving response from http request.

Comment: I try to use this via an Genymotion or normal android emu with different ip's and i still don't get any data from my php not even in the emulators browser. i've up dated my post with full log and my response from my PC web browser.

Comment: PC web browser results:                                                                {"museumItems":[{"id":"1","itemName":"Mona Lisa","artistName":"Unknown","itemLocation":"Athens","itemHistoricalPeriod":"1503 - 1506","itemImage":"image_folder\\mona_lisa"}],"success":1}

Comment: Sorry i used the wrong I.P. for genymotion the right one is 10.0.3.2. now i am getting response but i can't put my data on the right textView on my results activity. i get a blank activity.